# Input text into dynamic calendar widgets using Java Selenium

Tags: java, html, angular, selenium, automated-tests

I'm new to selenium and I have 3 pairs of calendar widgets that get created dynamically with dynamic ids. Each pair consists of a Start Date and End Date which can input in the form of 31/11/2017. How do I input start date and end date into each pair.

I'm not sure of the the next step from here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(
            By.xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'ctl00_btnAircraftMapCell')]"));
            elements.get(i).sendKeys("10/11/2017");
    }
```

My intention is to have a pair of 
start date as: 10/11/2017; 12/11/2017; 11/13/2017
 end date as : 11/27/2017; 11/28/2017; 29/11/2017

[image]

Comment: Is the order relevant? Are you trying to create three new records at the same time or edit existing records?

Comment: Can you share the relevant HTML please?